# User name in referral URLs

Tags: shortcode, urls

I want to change the referral link structure

Currently it's:

```
https://www.example.com?pkey=K9HBTKOYZ8
```

I want to change it to:

```
https://www.example.com/?pkey=username
```

User ID shortcode

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_ID();


function mwb_wpr_create_referral_code()
    {
        
        $length = 10;
        $pkey = '';
        $alphabets = range('A','Z');
        $numbers = range('0','9');
        $final_array = array_merge($alphabets,$numbers);
        while($length--)
        {
            $key = array_rand($final_array);
            $pkey .= $final_array[$key];
        }
        
        return $pkey;
    }
```

Comment: Presumably your existing code stores the random referral code somewhere so that it can be used again or looked up? That's probably the bit you want to replace with the username, not the random generation code. I'd guess it's stored as usermeta? Or is it some other table?

Comment: yes it being used again buyt with class "mwb_wpr_create_referral_code" and "$pkey"

so if I can manage to get the $user_name here at $pkey my problem will be solved,

Kindly help

Comment: how to clear user meta ?

Comment: Do you have SQL access to the database, by connecting MySQL Workbench to it over directly or e.g. with phpMyAdmin or your hosting control panel? Look in the wp_usermeta table for this referral code. I don't know what the meta_key will be for it because you haven't shown us that code. You can then delete the rows or change them from there.

Comment: existing users code is the same, after I made changes to get the referral code with username all new users are generating referral code as I wanted them, but the referral functionality stopped working, 

now I have the desired referral link being generated for all new user but the function of the referral is dead,

its a rewards system plugin, if referral link is not working at per the function user will not get reward

Comment: I check with data base with meta user and also install DB checker plugin there are orphan data I deleted them but still no use

Comment: Then maybe it's not stored in user meta then? I don't know for sure that's where it's stored, sorry, I was just guessing. You're going to have to find the code that stores these referral codes, and the code that handles referral links, to work out why this isn't working anymore.